# Time series plot in pandas and plotly

Tags: pandas, plotly

Consider I have the following data set

```
Date Gender State Annualincome
1/1/2017 Male A 100
1/1/2017 female B 200
2/1/2017 male B 190
2/1/2017 female A 210
```

How to plot this time series plot in pandas where The x axis is the date and the y axis is the annual income and the plot is grouped by gender and state where there is one trace for female in state A another trace for female in state B and so on ?

Comment: py.iplot(
    {
        'data': [
            {
                'x': df['Date'],
                'y': df['annualincome'],
                'name': gender, 'mode': 'markers',
            } for gender in df['gender'].unique()
        ],
        'layout': {
            'xaxis': {'title': 'x'},
            'yaxis': {'title': "y"}
        }
}) But this is only for gender. I dont know how to add state to this

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) for reshape data, last [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.pivot_table(index='Date', 
                    columns=['Gender','State'], 
                    values='Annualincome', 
                    aggfunc='mean',
                    fill_value=0)
print (df)
Gender     female      male     
State           A    B    A    B
Date                            
2017-01-01      0  200  100    0
2017-02-01    210    0    0  190

df.plot()
```

Comment: grouped = df.groupby(['gender','state'], as_index=False)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

for label, grp in grouped:
    grp.plot(x="Date", y='annualincome', ax= ax1, label = label,figsize = (10,10))
plt.show() How to convert this into plotly code?

Comment: Hmm, do you need for each category separate graph?

Comment: Yes. One trace for female from state A.. Another trace for female state B and so on